# Best decoupling capacitor part or series?

Tags: motor, driver, decoupling-capacitor

I am using motor driver, for PVDD as per datasheet I provided decoupling capacitors 100nf  close to each pins (4pins) and a bulk capacitor 10uF as common both are X7R ceramic. I see some article stating having multiple capacitors will create antiresonance. Let me know how can I avoid it? or any capacitor part number or series, which is best for decoupling capacitor..

Comment: There are many applications for "decoupling" for a general question to ask about. While someone might write such a general answer, I would strongly suggest keeping it focused. Have you reviewed related questions such as: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/59325/whats-the-use-of-a-decoupling-capacitor-near-a-reservoir-capacitor https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/172447/where-did-the-value-of-0-1uf-for-bypass-capacitors-come-from https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/275247/what-are-the-indicators-of-insufficient-decoupling etc.?

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is when you use caps of different sizes. The problem is the combined ESR/ESL and capactiance of different sized caps creates antiresonance. This is usually not a problem unless you have something going on the in +100MHz range. One way to avoid it is to use low ESR/ESL caps. Another way is to use multiple caps which will parallel ESR/ESL and improve the overall filtering of the capacitors. Be sure to take care on the ESR and ESL of the layout when the design is sensitive. If you aren't worried about EMI compliance then don't worry about it.

[image]
Source: https://techweb.rohm.com/know-how/nowisee/7669/

Comment: Thanks Voltage spike. I am very much concerned about the emi compliance..